# EnrichWith not running

Tags: c#, structuremap, decorator

I'm trying to get a really simple version of the decorator pattern running with StructureMap, but I can't get it working. Here is my code (note the breakpoints):

```
public interface ITestClass { void DoSomething(); }

public class TestClass : ITestClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing something"); //Breakpoint
    }
}

public class LoggingTestClass : ITestClass
{
    private ITestClass originalClass;

    public LoggingTestClass(ITestClass original)
    {
        originalClass = original; //Breakpoint
    }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Log start");
        originalClass.DoSomething();
        Console.WriteLine("Log finish");
    }
}
```

And in my registry:

```
For<ITestClass>().Use<TestClass>().
EnrichWith(original => new LoggingTestClass(original));
```

And finally a test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void DoSomeTesting()
    {
        using (IContainer container = new Container(new ApiRegistry()))
        {
            ITestClass testClass = container.GetInstance<TestClass>(); //Breakpoint
            testClass.DoSomething();
        }
    }
```

When I debug the test I hit the breakpoint in the test first, then the breakpoint in the DoSomething() method. The constructor of LoggingTestClass never gets executed.

I'm not sure how I could simplify it down any further, it seems that EnrichWith is simply not being called...

Comment: Just checked and I get the same problem with
For<ITestClass>().Use<TestClass>().OnCreation(x => x.DoSomething());
The DoSomething method only gets called by the test, not OnCreation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, it appears I am monumentally stupid! I was using `GetInstance<TestClass>` instead of `GetInstance<ITestClass>`. That little I has been keeping me busy for couple of hours! Go about your business people.